# Call a custom class in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have a very rough project that done partially in zend framework (not ZF2). The **'application'**, **'library'** and **'public'** folders are on the same root. Now i need to create a library **'Anil'** in the *'library'* folder at the same level where **'zend'** is located.

I tried it by adding following lines in *bootstrap.php* :

```
protected function _initAutoload()
{   
  Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('Anil');    
}
```

Then inside the **'Anil'** folder I created **Anil_Test.php** :

```
class Anil_Test{

}
```

And in the controller file I added following lines :

```
$myTest= new Anil_Test();
```

But it shows a Fatal error :

**Fatal error: Class 'Anil_Test' not found in.....**

I know I have done something silly here because this is my first project in Zend Framework. I believe the problem is the folder structure. I can do nothing with that because 50% of the project has already been coded.

Thanks in advance.
ANIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name should be `library/Anil/Test.php`. ;-)